# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS , MATE , Pc Freezes , image ultra blurred

Tags: 18.04, freeze, mate, pidgin

This happening after i start my pc and i am opening a few programs at the same time(Firefox,Pidgin and lutris(most of the times i load a game also) .

this is a standard opening from my side , but lately(3-4 days) my pc is freezing and i am unable to restart it.
[picture taken during the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McCh6.jpg)

Comment: Does this always happen when you are using lutris/wine?

Comment: not always , i checked my tempatures and are raised...i will open up my tower to check it in a few mins.